# Zip xml nodes using xquery?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

I have the following xml.

```
declare @x xml = '
<Cols>
    <Col><Name>A</Name></Col>
    <Col><Name>B</Name></Col>
    <Col><Name>C</Name></Col>
    <Col><Name>D</Name></Col>
</Cols>
<Values>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>2</B>
    <C>3</C>
    <D>4</D>
</Values>
';
```

How to write `select @x.query('......')` to convert it to

```
<Cols>
    <Col><Name>A</Name><Value>1</Value></Col>
    <Col><Name>B</Name><Value>2</Value></Col>
    <Col><Name>C</Name><Value>3</Value></Col>
    <Col><Name>D</Name><Value>4</Value></Col>
</Cols>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems following is doing what you need:

```
select @x.query('
    element Cols {
      for $c in /Cols/Col
        return
          <Col>
           { $c/Name }
           { element Value { text {/Values/*[local-name()=$c/Name/text()[1]]} } }
          </Col>
    }
  ');
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for regarding the Column names at all, everything we need is contained in `<Values/>`:

```
for $value in //Values/*
return element Col {
  element Name { local-name($value) },
  element Value { $value/node() }
}
```